# Android Error : unfortunately (MyAppName) has Stopped

Tags: java, android, android-intent

when using android studio to make login page .. I made edit text that receive the user age, if his age less than 18 years old he can't login , else he can ,, but when i built the project this message appear; unfortunately (MyAppName) has Stoped,,, what is the error with this code ?

```
public void checkButtonjjListener(){
    txtAge =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
    num = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());
    check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
    check.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if( num <18){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry, Your age Must not be less than 18 years old",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You can login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}``
```

Comment: Add stacktrace from logcat

Comment: post what you see in logcat `errors`

Answer (score 4):

Move under `onClick(...)`

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
  .......
  num = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());
  if( num <18){
  ........
  }
```

because `txtAge.getText().toString()` is `empty`

Comment: Do tell why that is necessary

Answer (score 0):

See your problem is apparent. I will explain you why your app is crashing.

The real problem is here

```
num = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());
```

You are trying to take the text from the EditText and parse it as integer. But you are doing this before the click listener. It should be inside the click listener's `onClick()` method.

```
check.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText().toString());

                    if( num <18){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry, Your age Must not be less than 18 years old",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You can login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

The exception must be `NumberFormatException` as you are trying to parse an empty string as an integer.

Just make the above mentioned changes and your app will work fine.